# How to update xml value with latest?

Tags: c#, xml

I have input.xml file like following.

```
<Root>
      <Main Name="Install">
        <Details>Success</Details>
        <Maintain>Install period</Maintain>
      </Main>
    <Main Name="Uninstall">
        <Details>failure</Details>
        <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
      </Main>
     <Main Name="Discard">
        <Details>failure</Details>
        <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
      </Main>
     <Main Name="Install">
        <Details>Done</Details>
        <Maintain>Got Output</Maintain>
      </Main>
    </Root>
```

I used this input.xml and write it on output.xml by using following code.

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load(@"C:\input.xml");
XmlNodeList MainNameList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Main");
XmlNodeList MainDetailsList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Main/Details");
XmlNodeList MainMaintainList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Main/Maintain");
for (int count = 0; count < MainNameList.Count; count++)
{
    string mainName = MainNameList[count].Attributes[0].Value;
    string mainDetails = MainDetailsList[count].InnerText;
    string mainMaintain = MainMaintainList[count].InnerText;
    XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmldoc.LoadXml("<Root></Root>");
    XmlNode MainNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("Root").AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Main"));
    MainNode.Attributes.Append(xmldoc.CreateAttribute("Name")).Value = mainName;
    MainNode.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Details")).InnerText = mainDetails;
    MainNode.AppendChild(xmldoc.CreateElement("Maintain")).InnerText = mainMaintain;
}
xmldoc.Save(@"C:\output.xml");
```

But I need output xml like following:

```
<Root>
 <Main Name="Uninstall">
   <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>uninstall period</Maintain>
 </Main>
 <Main Name="Discard">
    <Details>failure</Details>
    <Maintain>discard period</Maintain>
 </Main>
<Main Name="Install">
    <Details>Done</Details>
    <Maintain>Got Output</Maintain>
 </Main>
</Root>
```

i.e. I need Main element's latest entry only. Like the same for all element, latest element's details only should enter in output.xml file. help me for this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find `XDocument` from  `System.Xml.Linq` namespace easier to manipulate than `XmlDocument`. The code below does what you want (I think it's pretty self-explanatory):

```
        XDocument xDoc1 = XDocument.Load(inputFileName);

        var elems = xDoc1.Element("Root").Elements("Main");

        XElement xInstall = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Install");
        XElement xUninstall = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Uninstall");
        XElement xDiscard = elems.LastOrDefault(a => a.Attribute("Name").Value == "Discard");

        XDocument xdoc2 = new XDocument();

        xdoc2.Add(
            new XElement("Root", new XElement[]
            {
                xInstall,
                xDiscard,
                xUninstall
            })
        );

        xdoc2.Save(ouputFileName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any possiblities for getting this output by using xmldocument(using namespace system.xml)? @Arie

Comment: @GioFrog I guess you could do something similar with (I didn't test it):  XmlNode xnodeInstall = doc.SelectNodes("/Root/Main").OfType<XmlNode>()
                .LastOrDefault(a => a.Attributes["Name"] != null && a.Attributes["Name"].Value == "Install");

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's working for one node. But I have so many main elements and I used following code: XmlNodeList MainNameList = xml.SelectNodes("/Root/Main");. I can't use your logic for above XmlNodeList(like array of main elements). Implement by using XDocument(using namespace System.Xml.Linq) is also ok for me. I tried but I can't get correct output. help me on this. thanks @Arie

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, and you want every last main element with distinct name attribute, then this should work for you. You just need to change the path to input and ouput elements

```
try
{
       const string uninstallName = "Uninstall";
       const string installName = "Install";
       const string discardName = "Discard";
       const string nameAttribute = "Name";
       const string mainElement = "Main";
       const string rootElement = "Root";

       XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("../../input.xml");
       XElement root = xdoc.Root;
       if (root == null)
           throw  new Exception("No root element found");
       var mains = root.Elements(mainElement);
       if (!mains.Any())
           throw new Exception(String.Format("No element named {0} was found", mainElement));
       var lastInstall = mains.LastOrDefault(m => m.Attribute(nameAttribute).Value == installName);
       var lastDiscard = mains.LastOrDefault(m => m.Attribute(nameAttribute).Value == discardName);
       var lastUninstall = mains.LastOrDefault(m => m.Attribute(nameAttribute).Value == uninstallName);

       XDocument output = new XDocument();
       output.Add(new XElement(rootElement));
       if (lastUninstall != null)
           output.Root.Add(lastUninstall);
       if (lastDiscard != null)
           output.Root.Add(lastDiscard);
       if (lastInstall != null)
           output.Root.Add(lastInstall);
       output.Save("output.xml");

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     // log, write to output or anything
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is there any possiblities for getting this output by using xmldocument(using namespace system.xml)? @Martin